# cannot upload image with Alamofire to my server

Tags: php, ios, swift, alamofire, backend

I am trying to just upload one image to my server but my code is not working.Here is my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var theOneImage: UIImageView!
let url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Twitter/UploadImage.php"
let avaImage = UIImage(named: "cupid")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    theOneImage.image = avaImage

    uploadImage(image: avaImage)
}

func uploadImage(image : UIImage?){
    let imageData = avaImage?.pngData()
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
        MultipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image")
    }, to: url) { (encodingResult) in
        switch encodingResult{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON{ response in
                print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                print(response.response!) // URL response
                print(response.data!)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }

            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is my php code:

```
    if (empty($_FILES["image"])){
    $response = array("error" => "no data");
}else{
    $response["error"] = "NULL";
    $filename = uniqid() . ".jpg";
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['test'],'/ava')){
        $response["status"] = "success";
        $response["filepath"] = "http:" . $filename;
        $response["filename"] = "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    }else{
        $response['status'] = "Failure";
        $response['error'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["error"];
        $response['name'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $response['path'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $response['type'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["type"];
        $response['size'] = "".$_FILES["image"]["size"];
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

the response I am getting is telling me that in UploadImage.php, $_FILE["image"] is empty

here is my directories of my server:
[server screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVjlO.png)

please help. Thank you all!

Comment: 404 usually means "not found", are you uploading to the right endpoint?

Comment: oh thanks i forgot to include .php. This time I got a JSON but it shows "no data". According to my php file this means $_FILE["image"] is empty

Comment: Are we sure backend is working properly? I have no clue on PHP but I might figure out whats the problem with Swift

Comment: I can send the request successfully but the problem is that the back end is not receiving my image. It seems like swift is not sending data properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having issue uploading image using Alamofire and Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902787/having-issue-uploading-image-using-alamofire-and-swift-4)